# How to get TV image to computer?

Tags: hdmi, tv, desktop-computer

I have a TV (LG55LM620T) with [Mini-SCART (RGB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART) out and a All-In-One computer (Acer Aspire 7600U) with HDMI In on it.

How can I transfer the TV-image to the computer?

Any converter for SCART Mini to HDMI available?

Any way of transferring this signal wirelessly?

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer the TV image to the computer": Save/Process it on the computer itself, or just display it in real-time on your All-in-One?

Comment: I solved the problem by using a SCART to USB capturing device instead. By the way, I don't see why this was not a real question? Please motivate why you close threads!

Answer (score 1):

That system does *not* have HDMI in to the system, but to the monitor itself. Meaning that you won't see the Computer picture, but still need the computer on.

What you will need is an HDMI capture card (if one exists). One issue as well is that it needs to be HDCP compliant, which would probably prevent you from recording it.

There are converters available, especially if you go to Startech (good selection for North America, not sure other countries), but you will be looking at $70+, plus shipping